# Como fazer um download de arquivo para o servidor com php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, download

Gostaria de saber como faço o download de uma imagem ou video utilizando Laravel e salvar no meu servidor direto, pegando uma url como exemplo: `https://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/beats.png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro criamos os campos na View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/arquivos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Depois criamos a rota para o Controller:

```
Route::post('/arquivo', 'ArquivoController@store');
```

Aqui você pode usar os métodos padrões do PHP como:

Para verificar se um arquivo foi enviado

```
if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'arquivo' ][ 'name' ] ) && $_FILES[ 'arquivo' ][ 'error' ] == 0 )
```

Pega a extensão e restringe somente para imagens:

```
$extensao = pathinfo ( $nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
$extensao = strtolower ( $extensao );

if ( strstr ( '.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao ) ) {

    $novoNome = uniqid ( time () ) . '.' . $extensao;
    $destino = 'imagens / ' . $novoNome;

    if ( @move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_tmp, $destino ) ) {
        return 'sucesso ao enviar! ';
    } else {
       return 'erro ao enviar!';
    }
}
```

Aqui no caso os arquivos vão ser salvos no diretório: /public ou /public/imagens já que nos códigos criamos esse diretório.

Na documentação do Laravel existe uma classe especifica para lidar com isso a Storage.
Para usa-la você precisara criar um link simbolico entre as pastas do seu projeto laravel: public/storage, storage/app/public, você deve fazer isso como uma medida de segurança: é só ir no console na pasta do seu projeto e usar o comando:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Depois você precisa referenciar a classe Storage no seu controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Storage; // <--------
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArquivoController extends Controller
{
```

Então você usa o metodo request(); para pegar as informações do arquivo:

```
$arquivo = new Arquivo(); // cria uma instancia do arquivo 

$arquivo->nomeArquivo = request()->file('arquivo')->getClientOriginalName();
$arquivo->destino = "imagens/";
$arquivo->extensao = strtolower(request()->file('arquivo')->getClientOriginalExtension());
$arquivo->tamanho = request()->file('arquivo')->getSize();

if ( strstr ( '.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $arquivo->extensao ) ) {
    // Verifica se exite o diretorio, se não cria o diretorio;
    if (!Storage::exists("public/".$arquivo->destino)) {
        Storage::makeDirectory("public/".$arquivo->destino, 0777, true);
    }

    Storage::put("public/".$arquivo->destino, file_get_contents(request()->file('arquivo')));

    $arquivo->save(); // salva um registro no banco de dados sobre esse arquivo

    return "Imagem enviada com sucesso!";
} else {
    return "Erro! Tipo de Arquivo não é uma imagem!";
}
```

Para conseguir a url do arquivo você usa esse código aqui:

```
$arquivo = Arquivo::findOrFail($id);

$url = Storage::url($arquivo->destino."/".$arquivo->nome);

return $url;
```

Se você quiser disponibilizar para que o usuário baixe a imagem você pode redirecioná-lo para outra pagina para que ele baixe, aqui eu não usei o Storage, mas ele também tem um método para baixar:

```
$arquivo = Arquivo::findOrFail($id);

return response()->download(storage_path("app/public/".$arquivo->destino."/".$arquivo->nome));
```

Aqui estão alguns sites que eu usei para fazer o upload de arquivos:

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp), tem um tutorial bem básico de como fazer usando métodos nativos do PHP, porem está em inglês.

[Eduardokraus](https://php.eduardokraus.com/upload-de-imagens-com-php), tutorial em português usando métodos nativos do PHP.

[Documentação Laravel v5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem), A documentação do laravel sobre o sistema de arquivos que eles criaram, aqui tem mais detalhes sobre o Storage. A documentação é em inglês, mas recomento que a leia com ajuda de um tradutor, pois explica toda a funcionalidade da classe. Eu usei a 5.5.

Se você quiser usar um sistema de Drag&Drop para fazer o upload de arquivos recomendo esses tutoriais (precisa de JavaScript/Jquery):

[talkerscode](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/drag-and-drop-image-upload-using-ajax-jquery-and-php.php), o unico problema desse site é que ele é muito poluído.

[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/), esse tem um tutorial mais apresentável, mais é um pouco mais complicado.